# In SQL, does groupby on an ordered query behave the same as doing both in the same query?

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Are the following queries identical, or might I get different results (in any major DB system, e.g. MSSQL, MySQL, Postgres, SQLite):

Doing both in the same query:

```sql
SELECT group, some_agg_func(some_value)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY group
ORDER BY some_other_value
```

vs. ordering in a subquery:

```sql
SELECT group, some_agg_func(some_value)
FROM (
    SELECT group, some_value
    FROM my_table
    ORDER BY some_other_value
) as alias
GROUP BY group
```

Comment: MS Sql Server would not run either query: the first because it references a column from the original table outside the group by, and since group by rolls up multiple rows for each group almost by definition, you can't know for sure which row in each group to look at to get the value. The second order by inside a nested select is meaningless. In theory it shouldn't hurt, but it _definitely_ won't help and in practice is almost always means a mistake, so Sql Server tells you this. Personally, I'd prefer a warning here, but meh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the first sample:

```
SELECT group, some_agg_func(some_value)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY group
ORDER BY some_other_value
```

Let's think about what `GROUP BY` does by looking at this imaginary sample data:

```
A   B
-   -
1   1
1   2
```

Then think about this query:

```
SELECT A
FROM SampleData
GROUP BY A
ORDER BY B
```

The GROUP BY clause puts the two rows into a single group. Then we want to order by `B`... *but the two rows in the group have different values for B*.  Which should it use?

Obviously in this situation it doesn't really matter: there's only one row in the results, so the order is not relevant. But generally, how does the database know what to do?

The database could guess which one you want, or just take the first value, or the last — whatever those mean in a setting where the data is unordered by definition. And in fact this is what MySql will try to do for you: it will try to guess are your meaning. But this response is really inappropriate. You specified an in-exact query; the only correct thing to do is throw an error, which is what most databases will do.

---

Now let's look at the second sample:

```
SELECT group, some_agg_func(some_value)
FROM (
    SELECT group, some_value
    FROM my_table
    ORDER BY some_other_value
) as alias
GROUP BY group
```

Here it is important to remember databases have their roots in relational set theory, and what we think of as "tables" are more formally described as **Unordered** Relations. Again: the idea of being "unordered" is baked into the very nature of a table at the deepest level.

In this case the inner query can run and create results in the specified order, and then the outer query can use that with GROUP BY to create a new set... but just like tables, query results are *unordered relations*. Without an ORDER BY clause the final result is also unordered by definition.

Now you might *tend* to get results in the order you want, but the reality is all bets are off. In fact, the databases that run this query will tend to give you results in the order in which they first encountered each group, which will not tend to match the ORDER BY because the GROUP BY expression is looking at completely different columns. Other databases (Sql Server is in this group) will not even allow the query to run, though I might prefer a warning here.

---

So now we come to the final section, where we must re-think the question, like this:

> How can I use GROUP BY on the one `group` column, while also ordering by `some_other_column` not in the group?

The answer is each group can contain multiple rows, and so you must tell the database which row to look at to get the correct (specific) `some_other_column` value. The typical way to do this is with another aggregate function, which might look like this:

```
SELECT group, some_agg_func(some_value)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY group
ORDER BY some_other_agg_func(some_other_column)
```

That code will run without error on pretty much any database.

Just be careful here. On one hand, when people want to do this it's often for the common case where they know every record for `some_other_column` in each group will have the same value. For example, you might GROUP BY UserID, but ORDER BY Email, where of course every record with the same UserID should have the same Email address. As humans, we have the ability to make that kind of inference. Computers, however, don't handle that kind of thinking as well, and so we help it out with an extra aggregate function like `MIN()` or `MAX()`.

On the other hand, if you're not careful sometimes the two different aggregate functions don't match up, and you end up showing the value from one row in the group, while using a completely different row from the group for the ORDER BY expression in a way that is not good.

Answer (score 2):

Tables are unordered sets of data. A query result is a table. So if you select from a subquery that contains an `ORDER BY` clause, that clause means nothing; the data set is unordered by definition. The DBMS is free to ignore the `ORDER BY` clause. Some DBMS may even issue a warning or error, but I suppose it's more common that the `ORDER BY` clause just has no effect - at least not guaranteed.

In this query

```
SELECT group, some_agg_func(some_value)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY group
ORDER BY some_other_value
```

you try to order your results by `some_other_value`. If this is meant to be a column, you can't, because that other column is no part of your results. You'll get a syntax error. If `some_other_value` is a fixed value, then there is nothing ordered, because you'd have the same sort key for every row. But it can be an expression based on your result data (group key and aggreation results) and you can order your result rows by that.

In this query

```
SELECT group, some_agg_func(some_value)
FROM (
    SELECT group, some_value
    FROM my_table
    ORDER BY some_other_value
) as alias
GROUP BY group
```

the `ORDER BY` clause has no effect. You could just as well just select `FROM my_table` directly:

```
SELECT group, some_agg_func(some_value)
FROM my_table as alias
GROUP BY group
```

This gets the results unordered (or at least the order you see is not guaranteed to be thus every time you run that query), because your query doesn't have an `ORDER BY` clause.